# Jackson and JAX-RS: type resolving abstract types based on @PathParam

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

Suppose `Animal` is an abstract class in my project, and I have a REST resource (on a JAX-RS server, using Jackson for (de)serialization) for a `PUT` to manipulate animals that are stored in my database. They have concrete types, and the REST resource specifies the type in the path of the request:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{entityType}/{id: \\d+}")
public <T extends Animal> void putAnimal(@PathParam("entityType") String entityType, @PathParam("id") String id, Animal input) throws IOException {
    //...
}
```

I want to use `entityType` to pick the concrete class to deserialize with (`Dog` or `Cat` or whatever, for `entityType` being `dog` or `cat` or whatever). For reasons which are too complicated to explain here, I **cannot** put the type information in the JSON input itself.

So AIUI annotating `Animal` with a custom `TypeIdResolver` or something of the sort can't help me, because the type information won't be in the JSON itself (and that's all the info that the type resolver will get). I was planning to use a custom `MessageBodyReader`, but as far as I can tell, that doesn't get the other parameter values from the body passed in its `readValue` method, so I won't know what to deserialize into.

What am I missing? If this approach fails, how can I accomplish what I want without specifying animal-specific endpoints (which leads to lots of duplicate code as well as a loss of generality - right now I can add an subclass of `Animal` and this code will Just Work, which is very nice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below quote from the JAX-RS specification (5.2.2 URIs and URI Templates) suggests that you should be able to inject a `UriInfo` instance into your custom `MessageBodyReader`, and use one of its methods to inspect the URL path of the request.

> An instance of UriInfo can be injected into a class field or method parameter using the @Context an- notation. UriInfo provides both static and dynamic, per-request information, about the components of a request URI.

The example provided there shows a resource method receiving a `UriInfo` parameter, but normally it should be possible to inject an instance to a provider (`MessageBodyReader`) as well.

After obtaining the `entityType` path param through the `UriInfo`, your `MessageBodyReader` should be able to provide the corresponding sublclass of `Animal`.

Comment: Tested, worked flawlessly the first time. Awesome, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Given what you are trying to do you are better off building an `AnimalResource` class which contains your basic methods and then building separate `DogResource`, `CatResource` and whatever other classes you need which extend `AnimalResource`.  This will allow you to obtain the correct subclass of `Animal` and so deserialize the input JSON correctly.

**Update**
An example of how this might be achieved.  Your base resource looks something like this:

```
public class AnimalResource<T extends Animal>
{
    private final transient AnimalService<T> service;

    public AnimalResource(final AnimalService<T> service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Get
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public T getbyId(@PathParam("id") final String id)
    {
        return this.service.findById(id);
    }

    // Other CRUD methods go here
}
```

And then your individual animals, assuming that they all have the same setup, are simply:

```
@Path("/cats")
public class CatResource extends AnimalResource<Cat>
{
    public CatResource(final CatService catService)
    {
        super(catService);
    }
}
```

for a cat and

```
@Path("/dogs")
public class DogResource extends AnimalResource<Dog>
{
    public DogResource(final DogService dogService)
    {
        super(dogService);
    }
}
```

for a dog.  They will inherit the standard CRUD methods from the parent, and any animal-specific methods can still go in the individual `*Resource` class.

Comment: As I already said in the question, that will lead to duplicate code and loss of generality. You've also not specified _why_ I'm better off doing that than my current approach. It's also not even practical in the project this happens in, because we will essentially add Animals at runtime. It's no fun to add JAX-RS resources at runtime.

Comment: First off, if you have concrete subclasses then there wouldn't be duplicate code but that's not your major problem.  Depending on how you create your subclasses (javassist?) you may or may not be able to use them with an `ObjectMapper`, but regardless you should look at building a filter.  The filter can access the full request, decide on the type, parse the input, and store the object so that you can retrieve it in the resource.  It'll all be quite manual, though...

Comment: If there were concrete subclasses, AIUI your approach would lead to 1-1 corresponding resource classes, which would be identical save for `s/cat/dog/` etc. That constitutes duplicate code to me. And yes, the manual-ness of it is what I'm trying to avoid. :-)

Comment: That's where the `AnimalResource` comes in, you have all the basic methods there and just subclass it to cat, dog, whatever which contains the `@Path`.  I'll put a quick example in.

Comment: Right, so here `CatResource` and `DogResource` are exact duplicates, save for `s/cat/dog/`, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not going to be able to do better than the example in terms of lines of code per resource.  Anything more dynamic will require way more setup code, but good luck with it.